Exposition of the Robertson–Seymour theorem
Are there any expositions of the Robertson–Seymour theorem (aka the graph minor theorem), except the original papers by Robertson and Seymour?
I saw Diestel's chapter on graph minors, but unfortunately the proof of the graph minor theorem itself there is only a very rough sketch.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any paper or book that would give more details or even just a summary of what's in each Graph Minor paper. Research papers like "A Simpler Algorithm and Shorter Proof for the Graph Minor Decomposition" can give you good a feel of some important parts, but they're still quite narrow and very technical. I'd look for lecture/seminar notes, in video form there's: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~jfgeelen/CO749/lectures.html

I second Jim Geelen's lectures.
